# Can your T lymphocytes be activated by dendritic cells that have different MHC II alleles?

Tags: immunology, transplantation

So it is clear that a T cell is activated by a dendritic cell by presenting to the T cell the MHC II and the foreign antigen. This is because T cells are taught to have high affinity for MHC II when bonded to a foreign antigen. Is it true that MHC II molecules never bond with the cells' own proteins? But the MHC I molecules can bond with the cells' own proteins AND with foreign antigens, right?

Are the MHC I types identical in all cells of the human body since all cells in an individual have the same MHC I alleles?

Can our T cells in the lymph nodes be activated by any MHC II type? Or does it have to be a particular type? For example, could a strangers' MHC II type which is different to mine activate my T cells in the lymph nodes? In the Janeways Immunology textbook it says "unless the graft shares at least some HLA alleles with the recipient, the T cells that are selected on host thymic epithe­lium cannot be activated by graft ­derived antigen ­presenting cells". So the answer must be no? Then what are alloreactive T cells?

If it is a no, why is there then transplantation acute rejection? In the same textbook it says "Donor dendritic cells in the graft (in this case a kidney) carry complexes of donor HLA molecules and donor peptides on their surfaces. The dendritic cells are carried via the blood to secondary lymphoid organs (a lymph node is illustrated here), where they move to the T‐cell areas. Here, they **activate the recipient’s T lymphocytes**, whose receptors can bind specifically to the complexes of **allogeneic** donor HLA (both class I and class II) in combination with donor peptides. After activation, the effector T cells travel in the blood to the grafted organ, where they attack cells that display the peptide:HLA molecule complexes for which the T cells are specific."

If I understood that correctly, it says that the T cells in the lymph nodes can be activated by MHC II molecules even if they are different from the recipients HLA alleles. But if I understood this incorrectly and it meant that the T cell are only activated if the recipient and donor share HLA alleles, then that makes more sense since it complements the first extract from the textbook that I quoted.

So then why do we try and find the donor that shares the HLA alleles with the recipient if it will lead to this acute rejection? Oh no, I am so confused.

But then could this, again from the same textbook, shine some light "Before naive alloreactive T cells can develop into effector T cells that cause rejection, they must be activated by antigen-presenting cells that express both the allogeneic MHC and co-stimulatory molecules. Organ grafts carry with them antigen-presenting cells of donor origin, sometimes called passenger leukocytes, and these are an important stimulus to alloreactivity". SO THERE ARE **ALLOREACTIVE** T CELLS? So there are T cells that react to a dendritic cell that do not have the same HLA II alleles? Then going back to the first extract that I quoted, why were the alloreactive T cells taken into use and hence activated (and hence allowed to go kill the infected cells) by the donor dendritic cell even though the dendritic cell has different MHC II alleles?

So the T cells can only recognise the infected cells that have the same HLA I alleles? So they cannot kill infected cells of the donor if those cells have different HLA I alleles? But the T cells can be activated by antigen representing cells of any HLA II allele? And so in transplantation the alloreactive T cells are activated and then go and kill the like cells of the donated tissue? Why is this not taken into use in hematopoietic stem cell transplantation when there is an infection? Apparently in this case the T cells can be activated by any MHC II type of the APCs (or not?) and it can only kill the infected cell with the same HLA I alleles? But then in the acute rejection the T cells can kill cells that have any MHC I type alleles? Yeah, so many conflicting sentences over here, please help...<3

In the attached image it shows that in hematopoietic stem cell transplantation the T cell can be activated by any APC but then in the first extract that I quoted it says otherwise. Images are related and from the same textbook I have been mentioning.

[image]

[image]